# Distribution of a random subset

Tags: probability

I have a puzzle that I know has a simple answer, but I can't figure it out. If a subset is produced by selecting each item of a set with equal probability, i.e.:

$\forall x \in X, P(x \in S) = p$

Then the size of the subset is normally distributed, with a mean of $|X| * p$, but how do I determine the standard deviation?

$|S| \sim N(|X| * p, ??) $

Comment: I guess you assume each selection are independent as well, then the size of the subset follows a Binomial distribution, i.e. $|S| \sim \text{Binomial}(|X|, p)$. It is well known that $E[|S|] = |X|p$ and $Var[|S|] = |X|p(1-p)$.

Comment: Of course!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the subset is not normally distributed, it is binomially distributed, with $n$ being $|X|$ and $p$ being your probability $p$.

The standard deviation of such a normal distribution is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$.

In the limit for very large $|X|$ this binomial distribution will be closely approximated by a normal distribution, with mean $\mu = |X|p$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{1-p}}$.

Comment: Are you certain of the standard deviation $\sigma$ you state, for the Normal approximation?

Comment: Let's see ... $\sigma$ is going to match the Binom $\sigma$ which will be $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ and $p$ will be $\mu/n$. So $n = \mu/p$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{(\mu/p)p(1-p)}$.  So the right expression must be $$\sigma = \sqrt{\mu(1-p)}$$.